# Is there a way to use logical or ( || ) in switch case?

Tags: java

I need to write a program which takes a user input of any month and returns the number of days in said month. Here is the code that i wrote.

```
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    out.print("Enter month : ");
    String month = keyboard.nextLine().toLowerCase();
    switch (month){
        case "january" :
            out.println("31 days");
            break;

        case "february" :
            out.println("");
            out.print("Is it a leap year (yes/no): ");
            String leap_year = keyboard.nextLine().toLowerCase();
            if (leap_year.equals("no")){
                out.println("28 days");
                break;
            } if (leap_year.equals("yes")){
                out.println("29 days");
                break;  
            } else{
                out.println("Invalid option.. Use yes/no only.");
                break;
            }
            
        case "march" :
            out.println("31 days");
            break;
        case "april" :
            out.println("30 days");
            break;

        case "may" :
            out.println("31 days");
            break;
        case "june" :
            out.println("30 days");
            break;

        case "july" :
            out.println("31 days");
            break;

        case "august" :
            out.println("31 days");
            break;

        case "september" :
            out.println("30 days");
            break;

        case "october" :
            out.println("31 days");
            break;

        case "november" :
            out.println("30 days");
            break;

        case "december" :
            out.println("31 days");
            break;
        default :
            out.println("Enter a correct month");
            break;

    }
    keyboard.close();
```

This code works properly but it seems quite dragged-out. Is there a way i can use or operator to make this code concise. Other suggestions are also appreciated.
Thanks :D

Comment: Play with this to simplify things. First line gets the current year. Second line gets the number of days in the supplied month number. It knows if the supplied year is a leap year. Third line prints the number of days in the supplied month of the supplied year: `int year = java.time.LocalDate.now().getYear(); int numOfMonthDays = java.time.YearMonth.of(year, 2).lengthOfMonth(); System.out.println(numOfMonthDays);`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To answer your question directly:

> Is there a way to use logical or ( || ) in switch case?

No, it doesn't work with the `||` operator. But there are other ways to do what you are after.

You can collapse all cases with the same body together:

```
switch (month){
    case "january" :
    case "march" :
    case "may" :
    case "july" :
    case "august" :
    case "october" :
    case "december" :
        out.println("31 days");
        break;

    case "february" :
        out.println("");
        out.print("Is it a leap year (yes/no): ");
        String leap_year = keyboard.nextLine().toLowerCase();
        if (leap_year.equals("no")){
            out.println("28 days");
            break;
        } if (leap_year.equals("yes")){
        out.println("29 days");
        break;
    } else{
        out.println("Invalid option.. Use yes/no only.");
        break;
    }

    case "april" :
    case "june" :
    case "september" :
    case "november" :
        out.println("30 days");
        break;

    default :
        out.println("Enter a correct month");
        break;
}
```

Or use the new `switch` syntax if you're using Java 14 or newer:

```
switch (month) {
    case "january", "march", "may", "july", "august", "october", "december" -> out.println("31 days");
    case "february" -> {
        out.println("");
        out.print("Is it a leap year (yes/no): ");
        String leap_year = keyboard.nextLine().toLowerCase();
        if (leap_year.equals("no")) {
            out.println("28 days");
            break;
        } else if (leap_year.equals("yes")) {
            out.println("29 days");
        } else {
            out.println("Invalid option.. Use yes/no only.");
        }
        break;
    }
    case "april", "june", "september", "november" -> out.println("30 days");
    default -> out.println("Enter a correct month");
}
```